# java.lang.StackOverflowError error when using Spring Batch with JtaTransactionManager

Tags: spring-batch, stack-overflow, jta, transactionmanager

I'm tring to use JtaTransactionManager with Spring Batch.

transactionManager is the Jta transaction manager that has been defined in the dependency project.

This is my Spring batch config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class IntegrationJobConfig implements BatchConfigurer {

@Inject
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Inject
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;

@Inject
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return transactionManager;
}

@Override
public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return  factory.getObject();
}

@Override
public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Override
public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
    JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorer = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
    jobExplorer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jobExplorer.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobExplorer.getObject();
}
```

and below how I launch the job from quartz scheduler job:

```
public class IncomingIntegrationJob extends QuartzJobBean {

@Inject
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Inject
private Job myJob;

 @Override
 protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) {

  JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
  builder.addDate("execDate", new Date());

  JobExecution result = jobLauncher.run(myJob, builder.toJobParameters());

 }
}
```

but when I launch the above jobLauncher, it throw StackOverFlowError, seems like the error is an infinite loop.

```
[m2016-06-12 14:58:00,108 INFO  [smrp-scheduler_Worker-1] [32morg.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
[m2016-06-12 14:58:00,420 INFO  [smrp-scheduler_Worker-1] [32morg.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
[m2016-06-12 14:58:00,423 INFO  [smrp-scheduler_Worker-1] [32morg.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
[m2016-06-12 14:58:00,551 ERROR [smrp-scheduler_Worker-1] [1;31morg.quartz.core.JobRunShell Job inbound-batch-group.inbound-batch-job threw an unhandled Exception: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.reflect.Method.hashCode(Method.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport$MethodCacheKey.<init>(AdvisedSupport.java:597) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:486) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:193) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy250.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy250.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

until the end:

```
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy250.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
Wrapped by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) [quartz-2.2.3.jar:?]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.2.3.jar:?]
```

- transaction is using AspectJ compiled time weaving

@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)

- dependency project is working with no issue when using the same transaction
- the error only occur in the project that I'm working on.

anyone can help me to point out what may cause the problem? 
thank you.

Comment: When you say "transaction is using AspectJ compiled time weaving", what do you mean?  Spring Batch handles transaction explicitly so adding your own transaction semantics (via `@Transactional` for example) will typically cause issues.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: @MichaelMinella : I have a similar problem too. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884087/websphere-stackoverflow-exception . There is something fishy with the spring jobLauncher.run . Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's been some time, but I had the same problem while migrating spring boot to version 2.

In the case that we need the transaction manager to be the same in our batch and in other modules in our app, we override the Batch configurer and the transaction manager.

The error was resolved in my case by having @EnableBatchProcessing proccess before the configuration of the batch configurer. So just put @EnableBatchProcessing on the runner worked for me.

Hope it helps.